# MySQL Select rows from last month however it contains(31/30/28 days) or leap year

Tags: php, mysql

Now, I have a mysql query to get the rows from last month where `date` is the  timestamp column like,

```
date BETWEEN date_format(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
AND last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

But the problem is, I am getting only the records of 30 days of the last month. Its working fine for the months with 30 days or lower. But for the months like December I need all the records of 31 days. What will be the correction here? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the "last month"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  :  For now the last month is `October` . When in January 2016, the last month is `December` . Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many references & at last I have got my exact answer. My final code is,

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the engine cannot use an index on `date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your instructions sir.

Comment: Were you able to use this query in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want data from the *previous* month, then you can use the trick of subtracting the current day of the month:

```
where date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) and
      date < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day)
```

Comment: Sir, unfortunately the code is returning no results! Should I post my full code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add plus 1 as minus deducted one date lower.